# How can I fetch data from url by class name or id using Flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, httprequest, backend

As you see in the title of the question, I need to fetch data **from URL** by **class name** or **id** in Flutter. There is some data I haven't got its JSON data, and I need them to display on my app. I could fetch data using the code in the below, but I can't fetch any data by class name or id because I don't know what I need to use. Please help me

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String stringResponse;

  Future fetcData() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get("www.example.com"); //Consider that the URL has just a string such as "This is a string."
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        stringResponse = response.body;
      });
    } else {
      
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    fetcData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Http request"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(stringResponse.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use FutureBuilder or add `then` callback for `fetcData`.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand again how can I fetch by "class name" or "id". I guess your answer isn't about my question. In fact, my question is like that there are two paragraph in HTML, and I want to fetch the paragraph which has id's "p1".

Comment: Use some html parser library. https://pub.dev/packages/html

Comment: Could you please share the demo code of your response body.

Comment: @BalasubramaniSundaram Actually I haven't got any code in the body, I just considered there are string paragraphs. 
For example; 
<p id="p1">First string</p>
<p id="p2">Second string</p> 

And I want to fetch first string by id.

Comment: @TirthPatel Thanks so much I'll check it out.

Comment: Thank you again. I solved my problem thanks to you. @TirthPatel 
Resolution:  parse(response.body).getElementById("p3").text; 
I implemented html library and I used this parse method and my problem was solved.

Comment: That's Awesome! :D

Answer (score 1):

here is package   [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http).

here is a complete method to get a response.

```
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
          ..badCertificateCallback =
              ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);


     return client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url)).then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json-patch+json');
      request.headers.set('accept', 'application/json');
      var response = request.close().timeout(new Duration(seconds: 5));
      return response;
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      var result = response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      return result;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      var result = onError.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      return result;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because not your phone issue, Maybe that's also an issue, But follow my code;

Following my local.properties file

```
sdk.dir=/Users/gloify/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/gloify/Downloads/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.minSdkVersion=27
flutter.targetSdkVersion=33
flutter.compileSdkVersion=33
```

and in app level build.gradle,

```
defaultConfig {
    
    applicationId "com.example.emito"
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
   targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

if you are setting localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger() as localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()

then this type of error will occur. Make sure your default config.

That's it
Thank you